# Prove a matrix has an inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
B^T & C
\end{bmatrix}
has the inverse
\begin{bmatrix}
D & -DBC^{-1} \\
-C^{-1}B^TD & C^{-1} + C^{-1}B^TDBC^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
whenever C and D = $(A - BC^{-1}B^T)^{-1}$ are nonsingular.

I tried to see if their multiplication results in $I_{2}$, but I got stuck.

Comment: Can you write where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: For example, I tried to see if $AD -BC^{-1}B^{T}D = I$. But i don't see how this give me result.

Comment: That statement in your comment is true, simply because of the definition of D. Now, you have to work through the other four components similarly.

Comment: You can also go the [other way round](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/136781/457090).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
&\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ B^T & C
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
D & -DBC^{-1} \\ -C^{-1}B^TD & C^{-1}+C^{-1}B^TDBC^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\\ &=
\begin{bmatrix}
AD - BC^{-1}B^TD & -ADBC^{-1} + BC^{-1} + BC^{-1}B^TDBC^{-1} \\
B^TD + -CC^{-1}B^TD & -B^TDBC^{-1}+CC^{-1}+CC^{-1}B^TDBC^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\\ &=
\begin{bmatrix}
(A-BC^{-1}B^T)D & (I-(A-BC^{-1}B^T)D)BC^{-1} \\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
\\ &=
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
If instead you choose to multiply in the reverse order, then you will have similar cancellations using $D=(A-BC^{-1}B^T)^{-1}$ and the fact that $C$ is invertible.

Comment: The multiplication in reverse order is not necessary because $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$

Comment: @Peter Good point!

Comment: Perfect answer (+1) . Should be accepted!